# Creating a dynamic aray which given input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python. I have a hexadecimal input looks like:

```
0110
```

I convert this hexadecimal numbers to the binary and it looks like:

```
00000001 0001000
```

After a while I want to create a dynamic array for keeping this values in the array and change size according to given input for example it can be `01100c` and array size will increase to 3. So, I use this code:

```
dynamic_arraylist = [ ]
print("Enter a hex for converting binary");
hexdec = input("Enter any number in Hexadecimal form: ");
bin_value = bin(int(hexdec,16))[2:]
bin_value = (8 - (len(bin_value)% 8)) * '0' + bin_value
bytes = [bin_value[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bin_value), 8)]
' '.join(bytes) 
number_length = len(' '.join(bytes))
elements = ' '.join(bytes) 


for i in range(number_length):
    data = int(elements)
    dynamic_arraylist.append(data)
```

However I get an error because of `data = int(elements)` this line of code probably it doesn't understand my code and it gives an error:

```
ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Is there any way to fix that problem?

Comment: Why are you converting your strings into int?

Comment: @toti08 First of all thank you for answer, I want to take elements of 00000001 0001000 and put in array be like dynamic_arraylisy[ "00000001"," 0001000"]

Comment: So if you're fine with these elements being strings do not convert them into integers, just append `elements` to your `dynamic_arraylist` and you're done.

Comment: Awe I works but I have one more thing, the length of string is 388 so it shows 368 times same thing but I want to show int he element of the string with seperate, Is this possible ? @toti08

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your point, could you please explain it one more time?

Comment: Of course, number of length 0110 gives 17, and is show 17 times ["00000001 0001000","00000001 0001000"... However I want to take output be like ["00000001"," 0001000"] and finish

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I got your point! You don't need the `for` loop, just do `dynamic_arraylist.append(elements)`.

Comment: Thank you @toti08 it helps but still have a problem, how can I seperate 00000001 0001000 and take them be like two different element of list, for example when I want to call first element of array I just want to see 00000001

Comment: What do you see if you try for example to print `dynamic_arraylist[0]`? That should address the first element of your array...

Comment: I see 00000001 00010000, but I want to seperate them and when I call the first element like you say, it should show only the 00000001

Comment: Actually what I try this: when the user enter 0110, the program should seperate them 01,10 and put the list of array @toti08

Comment: Sorry, then I don't get your problem: isn't the user supposed to enter the number in hex format (so something like `0x1A`, `0x02`, etc...)?

Comment: I mean 011002 or 032005 or 01300560 etc.

Comment: Are these supposed to be integers or hex?

Comment: They are hex, I want to try seperate them 2 by 2 and put into array, then convert to binary numbers in array

Comment: So the user enters a number and you separate it into 2-digits (hex) numbers, convert it and put it into an array?

Comment: Yes excatly, you understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize the discussion here because it's becoming a bit lengthy. Basically what you want is the user to enter a number that should be interpreted as many 2-digit hex values. So for example:

```
0110
```

should be interpreted as:

```
0x01
0x10
```

In order to do this I'd first split your input string into an array of 2-digit strings. Then I'd convert each element and append it to your binary elements array:

```
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2] for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]

for elem in strArray:
    bin_value = bin(int(elem,16))[2:]
    bin_value = (8 - (len(bin_value)% 8)) * '0' + bin_value    
    dynamic_arrayList.append(bin_value)
```

When the user enters `0110` this produces:

```
['00000001', '00010000']
```

Comment: Awee even the question took -2 point you safe my life thank you for that alot, I worked on it 2 days and finally you gave me the solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I guess the -2 was because your question was not completely clear...

Comment: No worry :) I'm happy to see the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The `int()` constructor does not accept strings with spaces, so you should `join` without one.

Change:

```
number_length = len(' '.join(bytes))
elements = ' '.join(bytes)
```

to:

```
number_length = len(''.join(bytes))
elements = ''.join(bytes)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your suggest @blhsing when I change the code the errors gone away but it change my hex decimal number 100010000